# ReactJs - share this button animation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to re-build this react js button animation to simplify, understand it better.

https://jsfiddle.net/jkogfwt5/6/

I am having issues with toggling the isOpen state.

```
//Constants 

// Diameter of the main button in pixels
const MAIN_BUTTON_DIAM = 90;
const CHILD_BUTTON_DIAM = 48;
// The number of child buttons that fly out from the main button
const NUM_CHILDREN = 5;
// Hard code the position values of the mainButton
const M_X = 490;
const M_Y = 450;

//should be between 0 and 0.5 (its maximum value is difference between scale in finalChildButtonStyles a
// nd initialChildButtonStyles)
const OFFSET = 0.4;

const SPRING_CONFIG = [400, 28];

// How far away from the main button does the child buttons go
const FLY_OUT_RADIUS = 130,
  SEPARATION_ANGLE = 40, //degrees
  FAN_ANGLE = (NUM_CHILDREN - 1) * SEPARATION_ANGLE, //degrees
  BASE_ANGLE = ((180 - FAN_ANGLE) / 2); // degrees

// Names of icons for each button retreived from fontAwesome, we'll add a little extra just in case 
// the NUM_CHILDREN is changed to a bigger value
let childButtonIcons = ['pencil', 'at', 'camera', 'bell', 'comment', 'bolt', 'ban', 'code'];


function toRadians(degrees) {
  return degrees * 0.0174533;
}

function finalChildDeltaPositions(index) {
  let angle = BASE_ANGLE + (index * SEPARATION_ANGLE);
  return {
    deltaX: FLY_OUT_RADIUS * Math.cos(toRadians(angle)) - (CHILD_BUTTON_DIAM / 2),
    deltaY: FLY_OUT_RADIUS * Math.sin(toRadians(angle)) + (CHILD_BUTTON_DIAM / 2)
  };
}


var range = _.range;

var SpinButton = React.createClass({
  init: function() {

    this.state = {
      isOpen: false,
      childButtons: []
    };

  },
  mainButtonStyles: function() {
    return {
      width: MAIN_BUTTON_DIAM,
      height: MAIN_BUTTON_DIAM,
      top: M_Y - (MAIN_BUTTON_DIAM / 2),
      left: M_X - (MAIN_BUTTON_DIAM / 2)
    };
  },
  initialChildButtonStyles: function() {
    return {
      width: CHILD_BUTTON_DIAM,
      height: CHILD_BUTTON_DIAM,
      top: M_Y - (CHILD_BUTTON_DIAM / 2),
      left: M_X - (CHILD_BUTTON_DIAM / 2)
    };
  },

  finalChildButtonStyles: function(childIndex) {
    let {
      deltaX,
      deltaY
    } = finalDeltaPositions(childIndex);
    return {
      width: CHILD_BUTTON_DIAM,
      height: CHILD_BUTTON_DIAM,
      left: M_X + deltaX,
      top: M_Y - deltaY
    };
  },

  openMenu: function() {

    console.log("openMenu");

    let {
      isOpen
    } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !isOpen
    });
  },

  render: function() {

    this.init();

    let {
      isOpen
    } = this.state;

    return <div > {
      range(NUM_CHILDREN).map(index => {
        let style = isOpen ? this.finalChildButtonStyles(index) : this.initialChildButtonStyles();
        return ( < div key = {
            index
          }
          className = "child-button"
          style = {
            style
          }
          />
        );
      })
    } < div
    className = "main-button"
    style = {
      this.mainButtonStyles()
    }
    onClick = {
        this.openMenu
    }
    /> < /div > ;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render( < SpinButton name = "SpinButton" / > ,
  document.getElementById('SpinButton')
);
```

the original source
https://medium.com/@nashvail/a-gentle-introduction-to-react-motion-dc50dd9f2459#.7xi8ym721

Comment: I've tried to update the isOpen object - but still not having an affect in toggling the children - https://jsfiddle.net/jkogfwt5/18/

Comment: Ok got a working base version -- https://jsfiddle.net/jkogfwt5/20/

Comment: _ but for the more advanced version - I don't know how to load in the required animation modules - https://jsfiddle.net/jkogfwt5/23/

Comment: Is there a jsfiddle version of this working?